# How to convert a date in the format DD-MM-YYYY_HH-MM-SS in PHP

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime

Here are 3 examples of date and time strings I have

```
08-01-2019_03-00-34pm
22-01-2019_02-05-06pm
30-01-2019_11-17-07am
```

I would like to convert these to Unix Time Stamps

For example I have tried this on the first one..

```
echo (strtotime("08-01-2019"));
```

This half works, as it gives me a timestamp of 1546905600 which translates back to the correct date, but obviously makes the time 12:00:00am by default. So I'm stuck with how to deal with the time bit

I understand there is a `str_replace()` function so as long as I know what format I need to make the time bit, I guess I could use that?

Comment: is it time `03-00-34` h:i:s ??

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', '08-01-2019_03-00-34pm');
```

You can then use it to get the timestamp

```
$date->getTimestamp();  // 1546977634
```

Comment: This works when I pass `08-01-2019_03-00-34pm` through as a literal string, however I won't be doing this as I'll be pulling in data dynamically from a table in a database. So for example if I pass though `row['file_name']` instead of a literal string it doesn't display anything.. even so when I do a `var_dump()` on `row['file_name']` it tells me it is a string

Comment: Using `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', $row['file_name']);` should work if it's in that format. If you're not getting a valid date using this, use `var_dump($row['file_name']);` to find out the exact format.